# Binary plist structure

Tags: c#, macos, plist

What is Mac OS X binary plist structure? I could easy understand the XML plist structure because it’s self explanatory, but I have no idea where to start with the binary one.

My ultimate goal is to read binary plists in C# programs.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Property_list

Comment: You can convert a XML plist into the binary format (and vice versa) with `plutil`.

Comment: @Bavarious: My goal is to read the plist in C#

Comment: @miku I can't use plutil

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this helps you:

- http://explanatorygap.net/2009/10/30/apple-have-documented-the-binary-plist-format/

and the linked source file, explaining the format:

- http://opensource.apple.com/source/CF/CF-550/CFBinaryPList.c